# Iterate an object along path

Tags: objects, path

I'm modelling a backpack. And want to recreate a zipper. So i cannot iterate and object along a path (yellow dotted lines on secong image). I used array modeifier but it doesn't work. Please suggest me a tool to implement it. If somebody wants to open a file and to tinker, path along which object is iterated called "Path", and object called "Shape". Thanks!!!

[image]
[Blender File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzRcZw4BAvc9amk3NmxRczlXWGM)

Comment: Did you try an array plus a curve modifier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the curve, ALT C to convert from mesh to curve, Ctrl A to apply rotation and scale, in edit mode select the first point of the curve, Shift S "cursor to selected", then in object mode set "Origin to 3D cursor" (in the T panel).

Select the shape mesh, Ctrl A Apply rotation and scale, Origin to 3D cursor, add an array modifier and then a curve modifier, choosing the curve as target.

I had to smooth the curve where it bends nearly 90 degrees.

[image]

Comment: Thanks i have not tried yet but i'm sure it works!